# pyomo and cplex parallel computing for mixed integer linear programming

Tags: parallel-processing, cplex, pyomo

I am using pyomo for mixed-integer linear programming model. I call cplex in pyomo to solve the model. The problem I am solving is large, which require parallel computing.

Should I set parallel in pyomo or in cplex?

In pyomo, I found this syntax, but seems not working.

```
solver_manager = SolverManagerFactory('pyro')
```

If set parallel in cplex, how to modify this syntax? To add something calling parallel computing?

```
result = opt.solve(inst, tee=True, warmstart=True)
```

I have no idea which way to proceed..Thanks for your help!

Best,
Lei

Answer (score 1):

By default, CPLEX should already be using parallel threads. For example, in the documentation for the [global thread count](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/Threads.html) parameter, we have:

> When this parameter is at its default setting 0 (zero), and your
>   application includes no callbacks or only an informational callback,
>   CPLEX can use all available threads; that is, at most 32 threads or
>   the number of cores of the machine, whichever is smaller. If your
>   machine offers more than 32 threads, you can take advantage of them by
>   increasing the value of this parameter.

In the pyomo documentation [here](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoOnlineDocs.html#_troubleshooting), it says:

> If there are troubles with solver (i.e., after Pyomo has output
>   "Applying Solver"), it is often helpful to use the option
>   --stream-solver that causes the solver output to be displayed rather than trapped.

If you do that, you should see the CPLEX log output on the screen. Look for a line like this:

> Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 8 threads.

If not, maybe it gives you a clue.

Comment: Yes, it shows parallel mode info. In other words, just leave the code alone, it directly uses parallel computing with solver CPLEX. Thanks, rkersh.